# Asp.net Export To Excel: Need to apply Excel formatting in data of two columns that i.e.<style> .amt{mso-number-format:\"\\#\\#0\\.00\";} </style>

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, export-to-excel

Code What I tried:

```
private void ExporttoExcel(DataTable table)
        {
            filename = "All_OS" + "_" + datepicker.Value.Replace("/", "-").ToString() +".xls";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<style> .amt{mso-number-format:\"\\#\\#0\\.00\";} </style>");            //sets font
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");
            //sets the table border, cell spacing, border color, font of the text, background, foreground, font height
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' "
                                               + "borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' "
                                               + "style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'> <TR>");
            //am getting my grid's column headers
            int columnscount = table.Columns.Count;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td colspan=23>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'><CENTER> ");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("All Outstanding " + datepicker.Value.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(" </CENTER></Font> ");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
            for (int j = 0; j < columnscount; j++)
            {
                  //write in new column
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                    //Get column headers  and make it as bold in excel columns
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(table.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {//write in new row
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(row[i].ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</font>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

Output
Actual Result
50
100
2,100.00
3,450.00

Expected Result
50.00
100.00
2,100.00
3,450.00

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

You can Use simply round the value in output:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.45678);
```

in Your Context:

```
 String.Format("{0:0.00}", row[i].ToString());
```